# How to find out UDF version of a DVD in Linux?

Tags: udf

`sudo cdrwtool -i -d /dev/sr4` and `dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/sr4` do not indicate the UDF version.
(1.02, 1.50, 2.00, 2.01, 2.50, 2.60)

#### How can I find out the UDF version of a DVD?

Comment: Trivial answer: `udisksctl info --block-device /dev/sr0 | grep Id`

Comment: _Id:                         
    IdLabel:                    
    IdType:                     
    IdUUID:                     
    IdUsage:                    
    IdVersion:_   is all blank.

Comment: Is the DVD blank? ... of course, I had `sr0` and you had `sr4` ... so... make sure the device name matches whatever you are testing.

Comment: @RubberStamp Device name matches. And the DVD inside was already formatted using Windows, because if there is **one thing** where Windows crushes Linux, it is UDF support. It works out of the box with Windows. Also packet writing just works. Pktsetup from only supports read only mount. And only works occasionally.

Comment: So, exactly how was the disc written... single session format, packet writing, multi-session... created using Windows built-in tools or separate program? etc... etc... More details will be needed to answer the question.

Comment: @RubberStamp Using the format GUi in Windows Explorer. UDF 2.01. Session 1 is closed but the disc is unfinalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **udfinfo** tool which is available from [udftools](https://github.com/pali/udftools) project since version 2.0.

```
$ udfinfo /dev/sr4
```

It prints lot of information about UDF filesystem, including two UDF revision numbers:

```
udfrev=2.01
udfwriterev=2.01
```

First one is minimal UDF revision needed to read UDF filesystem and second one is minimal UDF revision to write/modify UDF filesystem.

Another option is to use **blkid** tool from [util-linux](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux) project. But you need at least version 2.31.

```
$ blkid -p -s VERSION -o value /dev/sr4
```

It prints minimal UDF revision needed to read UDF filesystem:

```
2.01
```

Comment: Oh, you are this experienced _PaliUDF_ editor from Wikipedia? Nice to hear from you! It is an honour!

Comment: I'm author of udfinfo tool. So if you find any problem with it please report it on project page.